# Pandas Excel Export - Columns Out of Order

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, export-to-excel

I'm using `Output.to_excel('output.xls', index=True, header = False)`

However when I open the excel sheet the columns or out of order.

When I use `Output.to_csv('output.csv', index=True, header = False)`, the columns are in the appropraite order.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you set `header = True`?

Comment: @GurupadHegde I get a row on the top with some sort of index-esque/tuple header (probably because I transposed the `df` earlier). The rest stays the same.

Comment: Seems strange.  Perhaps you could force it with the kwarg:  `columns = df.columns.tolist()` ?

Comment: can you try something similar to this:
`>>> writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> Output.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> writer.save()`
and see if it works

Comment: @Plug4 Thanks for the suggestions, however using `ExcelWriter` and `writer.save()` produced the same out of order spreadsheet

Comment: Hmmm it seems they are ordered according to the index, which is the problem. And the index loops `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. So it is putting the `0`'s first and then the `1`'s, etc.

Comment: I used df.reset_index() to fix the ordering issues. thanks for the help stackoverflow

Comment: Don't be like me. I had this issue because I ordered the headers using {} instead of [].